# how to upgrade pidof command in terminal

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 16.10

hi i have a command error pidof command in ubuntu 16.10 i cannot get any program id (pid) except firefox so i searched it on this website:http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/pidof-not-working-properly-469341/ this websites says we could solve this through upgrading pidof command but i dont know how to upgrade this is very big issue for me
i have tried the following commands

```
sudo apt upgrade pidof
sudo apt-get upgrade pidof
```

Comment: I very much doubt that post from 2006 describes your problem so you'd better [edit] and show the exact commands you are using and output by copying and pasting them into your question and formatting as code `{}`

Comment: . . . a simple test case like `pidof bash` or `pidof pidof` might be useful. Also please show us `apt-cache policy sysvinit-utils` and `type pidof`.